# Autofac populate method fails on runtime

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, autofac, azure-functions

I'm currently creating an Azure Fucntion. The DI Layer is a .netstandard project.
I'm using autofac as my DI library. Everything compiles, but at runtime it gives me a **method not found exception**. I have read a bunch of articles saying that I need to upgrade all of my nuget packages. That doesn't help me one bit.
This is the code that fails

(.netstandard) DI Project -> InjectConfuguration.cs

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Awesomeness.AutofacInjection;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Protocols;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

... Some code here ..

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
    ... some code here ...
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

                containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new ApplicationModule());
                containerBuilder.Populate(services); // Exception here

                var applicationContainer = containerBuilder.Build();

               var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(applicationContainer);

                return serviceProvider;
```

Exception:

```
  Method not found: 'Void 
Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacRegistration.Populate(Autofac.ContainerBuilder, 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor>)'.
```

StackTrace

```
at ProjectName.Functions.DI.DIConfig.<>c.<.ctor>b__0_0(ContainerBuilder builder)
   at AzureFunctions.Autofac.Configuration.DependencyInjection.Initialize(Action`1 cfg)
   at ProjectName.Functions.DI.DIConfig..ctor()
```

(.net framework)Function Project -> Function1.cs

```
using System;
using Awesomeness;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, [Inject] IAwesomeClass awesomclass)
        {

            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            log.Info($"{awesomclass.VeryAwesomeMethod()} at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

I created a dummy project that replicates my error.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/j03x3v6c55gy1aq/Awesomeness.zip

Comment: What the line gives the exception? Can you post the full message of exception and stacktrace?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so that we can reproduce it on our own

Comment: I have added a project file that replicates the error

Comment: Please don't link to external files like .zip files, but instead show all the relevant parts that allow reproducing the problem _in the question itself_.

Comment: My browser treats your .zip file as dangerous. It looks like `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll` is not loaded at runtime for some reason. It often happens because of a declared dll version and an actual dll file inconsistency

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` to `ver. 3.1.4` worked in my case.